# Using scanf to fill out a multidimensional array (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, scanf, dynamic-arrays

I was wondering how to properly use scanf to fill out a multidimensional array.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int n; //number of rounds
int* sArray; //multidimensional array that holds the scores of both players
int i;

scanf("%d", &n);

sArray = (int*) calloc (n * 2, sizeof(int));


for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d", &sArray[i][1], &sArray[i][2]); 

}

return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error, "Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector." Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To dereference a two dimensional array you need a double pointer: `int** sArray;`

Comment: Just FYI, your #include statements should be before your main method.

Comment: Always check the function return value from `scanf` (the number of items successfully scanned).

Comment: To fill a two dimensional array you need two nested for loops

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Note how the inner loop is "unrolled" into single scanf.

Comment: Should be `int (*sArray)[2] = calloc (n , sizeof **sArray * 2);`

Comment: Yea, I just wrote the include statements after my main function here but my actual code has it placed correctly. Was done by mistake posting the question but thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Did you intend `... &sArray[i][0], &sArray[i][1])` indexing from `0` (you start at index `[1]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two dimentional array is defined as follows: `int sArray[N][M]`, but since you wanted to work with the dynamic memory I offer you to take a look at a pointer to pointer at `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int **sArray;
    sArray = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sArray[i] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d %d", &sArray[i][1], &sArray[i][2]);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to clean-up after you are done with the array.

As mentioned in the commentaries, You don't need to cast the result of `malloc` if you work with `pure c`. I did this because my c++ compiler refused to compile it without this cast.

You might need to check errors during a dynamic allocation of the array. Read more [here](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html)

Comment: That's fine, but please don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: That's not really a two-dimensional array, that is 1-dimensional array of pointers to 1-dimensional arrays (with massive memory overhead in this case). It is also possible to have actual 2-dimensional array of values.

Comment: @hyde Not if the C implementation you're using doesn't have VLAs, which is possible in C11.

Comment: @szczurcio You don't need VLA if other dimension is fixed at compile time, and here it is 2. So C89 is enough. Also, C99 already has VLA.

Comment: _A two dimentional array is defined as follows: int **sArray_...   A two dimensional array in C looks like: `int array[x][y];`  What you have is a pointer to pointer to int: `int **array;` that will be used to emulate a 2D array.

Comment: @ryyker, yes, you are right, I just check the K&R book about this topic.

Comment: _You don't need to cast the result of malloc_...  Sometimes (In C++) it is required.  Only in C is it not required, and not even recommended.  But it is good that you mentioned it.

Comment: @hyde Yeah, in C99 it's required that the implementation support it, but in C11 it's optional again (the motivation is unknown to me, but that's what they did). And it's not fixed at compile time here, the size depends on the value read from the user.

Comment: @szczurcio Oh right, misread your comment about C11. Anyway, [Christophe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34845312/1717300) shows what I meant about not needing VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

There are already a lot of good answers here on how to define your dynamic 2D array.  But this variant was not yet mentionned, so I put it for the records.

As the last dimension of your array is fixed, you could define your 2D array as follows:

```
int (*sArray)[2]; //multidimensional array that holds the scores of both players
...
sArray = (int(*)[2]) calloc (n, sizeof(int)*2);  // self explaining
```

In this way, all the elements will be stored contiguously (each n element of the allocated array, is 2 contiguous integers), without the need for an array to arrays.

The rest of your code remains identical. Except that you shoud address `sArray[i][0]` and `..[1]` instead of `[1]` and `[2]` and free memory at the end. In C array indexing starts always from 0 and goes to size-1.

Of course, this approach is strictly limited to 2D arrays where the last dimension is fixed.

**[Live demo with addressing](http://ideone.com/mTWnUj)**

Answer (score 0):

Usually to fill a bidimensional array you will use two nested for loops.
For example :

```
int array[2][3] = {0};

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
      scanf("%d", &array [i][k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    int n; //number of rounds
    int** sArray = malloc(2 * sizeof(int*)); //multidimensional array that holds the scores of both players
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sArray[0] = (int*)calloc(n , sizeof(int));
    sArray[1] = (int*)calloc(n , sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &sArray[0][i], &sArray[1][i]);
    }

    free(sArray[0]);
    free(sArray[1]);
    free(sArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is somewhat of a *painful* way to allocate that does not quite accomplish what you have set out to do. Look closely at the comment for how to allocate a *pointer-to-array 2 of type* `int` or at the other answer to allocating a *pointer-to-pointer-to type* `int`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Got it!

Comment: Uh, this is UB. You want to read `n` before passing it to `calloc`.